# How to hide Tab Bar on push in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, uitabbar

I'm struggling for last few days with `TabbedPage` in Xamarin.Forms on iOS. I found some solutions like those:
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/20901/hide-tab-bar-on-push

However, none of them works well. I also tried to subclass `TabbedRenderer` and set TabBar height to 0. It works, but if I hide TabBar in `NavigationPage.Pushed` event handler, there's some delay and for example TableView has blank space on the bottom.

If I try to override `NavigationRenderer` and hide/show Tab Bar in `PushViewController`/`PopViewController` methods it sometimes fails. For example if I navigate fast back and forth, method `PopViewController` is not invoked, NavigationStack is broken and Tab Bar is not restored.

I think that the only good solution would be to make this property work: `UIViewController.HidesBottomBarWhenPushed`. However, I have no idea how to do it, because setting/overriding it in renderers doesn't work.

Did anybody manage to successfuly show & hide TabBar?

Comment: Hi , did you have any question?

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to implement a solution which fixes the issue with blank space after hiding `TabBar`. You can read more details about it in [this article](https://wojciechkulik.pl/xamarin-forms/auto-hiding-tab-bar-on-navigation).

To solve the problem we just need to layout all `ChildViewControllers`. Here is my sample implementation of a custom `TabbedPage` and its `TabbedPageRenderer`.

**HideableTabbedPage.cs:**

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace HideTabBar.Controls
{
    public class HideableTabbedPage : TabbedPage
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty IsHiddenProperty =
            BindableProperty.Create(nameof(IsHidden), typeof(bool), typeof(HideableTabbedPage), false);

        public bool IsHidden
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(IsHiddenProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IsHiddenProperty, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

**HideableTabbedPageRenderer.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using HideTabBar.Controls;
using HideTabBar.iOS.CustomRenderer;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(HideableTabbedPage), typeof(HideableTabbedPageRenderer))]
namespace HideTabBar.iOS.CustomRenderer
{
    public class HideableTabbedPageRenderer : TabbedRenderer
    {
        private bool disposed;
        private const int TabBarHeight = 49;

        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement == null)
            {
                this.Tabbed.PropertyChanged += Tabbed_PropertyChanged;
            }
        }

        private void Tabbed_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.PropertyName == HideableTabbedPage.IsHiddenProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                this.OnTabBarHidden((this.Element as HideableTabbedPage).IsHidden);
            }
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            base.Dispose(disposing);
            this.disposed = true;
        }

        private async void OnTabBarHidden(bool isHidden)
        {
            if (this.disposed || this.Element == null || this.TabBar == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            await this.SetTabBarVisibility(isHidden);
        }

        private async Task SetTabBarVisibility(bool hide)
        {
            this.TabBar.Opaque = false;
            if (hide)
            {
                this.TabBar.Alpha = 0;
            }

            this.UpdateFrame(hide);

            // Show / Hide TabBar
            this.TabBar.Hidden = hide;
            this.RestoreFonts();

            // Animate appearing 
            if (!hide)
            {
                await UIView.AnimateAsync(0.2f, () => this.TabBar.Alpha = 1);
            }
            this.TabBar.Opaque = true;

            this.ResizeViewControllers();
            this.RestoreFonts();
        }

        private void UpdateFrame(bool isHidden)
        {
            var tabFrame = this.TabBar.Frame;
            tabFrame.Height = isHidden ? 0 : TabBarHeight;
            this.TabBar.Frame = tabFrame;
        }

        private void RestoreFonts()
        {
            // Workaround to restore custom fonts:

            foreach (var item in this.TabBar.Items)
            {
                var text = item.Title;
                item.Title = "";
                item.Title = text;
            }
        }

        private void ResizeViewControllers()
        {
            foreach (var child in this.ChildViewControllers)
            {
                child.View.SetNeedsLayout();
                child.View.SetNeedsDisplay();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Final result:**

[image: auto hiding tab bar]

Comment: For iPhone X is this not working btw. Have you got it working on the iPhone X?

Comment: Got it working on the iPhone X. You need to set the TabBarHeight to 83:


``private void UpdateFrame(bool isHidden)
        {
            var tabFrame = this.TabBar.Frame;

            if (TabBar.Frame.Height > 50)
                TabBarHeight = 83;

            tabFrame.Height = isHidden ? 0 : TabBarHeight;
            this.TabBar.Frame = tabFrame;
        }``

Comment: This solution works for me. Thanks. For people integration this. There will be 2 files in iOS, one TabbedRenderer and other one as Page Renderer.

Comment: @Wojciech: Do you have any solution for Android. I am using xamarin forms latest api to display tabbar on android to bottom but could not find any handler to hide the tabbar.

Comment: @ArunGupta I don't have a solution for android unfortunately, but I think it should be easier than on iOS. You can try to use those sources and modify renderer: https://github.com/thrive-now/BottomNavigationBarXF (I haven't tried it)

Comment: Hi, By using your solution, tabbar is hidden but it shows blank space. Any idea how to remove it ?

Comment: @GayatriGokhale check out my post: https://wojciechkulik.pl/xamarin-forms/auto-hiding-tab-bar-on-navigation . Also this project is on github, so you can check it out and find what you've missed in your example. It may be also related with Xamarin.Forms version.

Comment: Thanks . I will try and let you knoe

Answer (score 3):

There is a solution that doesn't require any renders and works on both Android and iOS.

Wrap the `TabbedPage` in a `NavigationPage` so the structure of your app becomes

- NavigationPage (root)

  - TappedPage

    - NavigationPage

      - ContentPage (with tabbar)
  - ContentPage (without tabbar)

On the TabbedPage you have to hide the navigationbar of the 'root' NavigationPage, otherwise you have 2 navbars.

```
<TabbedPage
    ...
    HasNavigationBar="False">
```

If you push a page using the 'root' `NavigationPage`, the tabbar is hidden and there is no blank space at the bottom.

See my example at:
https://github.com/Jfcobuss/HideTabbarExample/tree/master/HideTabbarExample

Comment: What version of forms are you using?

Comment: I tried with Xamarin.Forms 3.0.0 and it still works. Haven't tried with lower version yet

Comment: My mistake, I was thinking about different property. I think that latest Xamarin.Forms has property to hide tab bar. However, your solution changes behavior of the application, because in your case navigation doesn't happen within tab, but outside, which might not be expected if you want to keep different navigation stacks per tab.  Also you'll loose some built-in functionality like: back button won't be named after previous tab and navigation forward will cause sliding whole tab bar.

Comment: Yes your right. In my case I alway hide the backbutton title so this was not an issue for me. With this solution it would show the title of the TabbedPage. The animation not as smooth as should be indeed. I hope Xamarin will put effort in making `HidesBottomBarWhenPushed` work without renderers and blank space at the bottom

Comment: @JopCobussen Did you figured out how to remove the blank space at the bottom?

Answer (score 2):

What I have tried :

- Create subclass of ContentPage and create BindableProperty(like `HidesBottomBarWhenPushed`) inside it.  I set `ViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` in PageRenderer but it doesn't work, although I can get the value of this property .
- set `this.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` in the initial constructor in PageRenderer , still no luck.

I think it must be something wrong with `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` , we can not hide tabbar by this way.  As a temporary and simple workaround , I change the Visible of `TabBarController.TabBar` in  PageRenderer

```
class PageiOS : PageRenderer
{
    public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewWillAppear(animated);
        if (this.NavigationController != null && this.TabBarController != null)
        {
            bool isRootVC = this.NavigationController.ViewControllers.Length == 1;
            ParentViewController.TabBarController.TabBar.Hidden = !isRootVC;
        }
    }
}
```

It behaves like what you said above , there is some delay and blank space on the bottom . I disable the animation on the push and pop , and the issue disappeared.

Test:

[image]

Comment: sorry for late reply (I was on vacation) and thank you for your answer. I checked your solution and it hides tab bar, however even if I turn off animation, there is still blank space and my TableView doesn't enlarge to fill the space. Anyway, I need to keep those animations, so unfortuately it's not a solution for me :(

Answer (score 0):

I did manage to attain the desired result in a more "native way" using `HidesBottomBarWhenPushed` property. If you take a look into how navigation is implemented for iOS you would notice, that before pushing a new view controller into navigation stack [it gets wrapped in a parent view controller](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/2489ba0432533203caab734e936b53fe5f25dabb/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Renderers/NavigationRenderer.cs#L352) inside `CreateViewControllerForPage` method. It gave me a chance to intercept already created view controller that is not yet pushed to the navigation stack and set `HidesBottomBarWhenPushed` property. For that purpose I've created an empty class derived from `ContentPage`:

```
public class NoTabBarPage : ContentPage { }
```

So now every page derived from the `NoTabBarPage` wan't have bottom tab bar.

And also a renderer that makes everything work:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(NoTabBarPage), typeof(NoTabBarPageRenderer))]
namespace HideTabBar.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class NoTabBarPageRenderer : PageRenderer
    {
        public override void DidMoveToParentViewController(UIViewController parent)
        {
            base.DidMoveToParentViewController(parent);

            parent.HidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true;
        }

        public override void ViewDidLayoutSubviews()
        {
            base.ViewDidLayoutSubviews();

            if (View != null && View.Superview != null && View.Frame.Height != View.Superview.Frame.Height)
            {
                View.Frame = View.Superview.Frame;
                Element.Layout(View.Frame.ToRectangle());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As usual it couldn't go flawless with **Xamarin.Forms**, and it turned out, that child view controller is not stretched to frame of a parent view controller. And that I had to manually fix inside `ViewDidLayoutSubviews`.

[image]

Also beware, that every new view controller pushed to the navigation stack after view controller with hidden tab bar wan't have tab bar either. So in my case every "detail" page is derived from the `NoTabBarPage`.

Answer (score -1):

I have faced with an issue when I need to hide tab bar before it drawn on the screen.

The solution from Wojciech Kulik helped me but it started blinking on navigating to the tabbed page.

The code below solved my problem. Hope it'll be helpful for you.
Place it in your TabbedRenderer derived class

```
public override void ViewWillLayoutSubviews()
{
    OnTabBarHidden(true); // Hide before the page appear
}
```