# Xamarin form auto hide Toolbar and TabBar

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, toolbar, tabbar

I having trouble creating effect like auto hide Toolbar and TabBar in Xamarin.Forms page. For example in big basket app when you scroll the app, both Toolbar and TabBar auto hide.

I know it's easy to do in Xamarin.Android but how can I achieve this in Xamarin.Forms xaml?

Comment: If you have known how to achieve in xamarin android, you could achieve it by CustomRenderer, there is simple https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46119640/how-to-hide-tab-bar-on-push-in-xamarin-forms/52012805 ,you could refer to it.

Comment: Can you elaborate more?

Comment: Just see the example how chrome app on Android scroll it's navigation bar I want that kind of effect

Comment: You can achieve TabbedRenderer, then use the xamarin.android achievement in your control.

Comment: Thanks @LeonLu for replying but the thing is in native material design they use coordinator layout as root layout but the xamarin.forms usage Relative layout as I know as a root and adds the page as a view in the relative layout you can find code of onCreate method on Github as xamarin is open source we all know. In this case page is child view of android's Relative layout. Inside pagerenderer how to achieve this feature? I am struggling.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding Xamarin.Forms -->

I'm posting a simpler solution (although Xamarin still has some bugs to work out with this approach).

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

public class NoTabPage : ContentPage
 {
private ContentPage _myPage;
public NoTabPage(ContentPage page)
{
    _myPage = page;
    var navPage = new NavigationPage(new Page());
    navPage.PushAsync(new ContentPage(), false);
    navPage.PushAsync(_myPage, false);
    Navigation.PushModalAsync(navPage);

    navPage.Popped += navPage_Popped;
}

private void navPage_Popped(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Page != null && e.Page == _myPage)
    {
        Navigation.PopModalAsync();  //NOTE:  Application crashes on android when this setting is FALSE
        Navigation.PopAsync(false);
    }
}
}
```