# Xamarin Forms multiple NavigationPages

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a problem. In my app I have the following structure

- NavigationPage (root)

  - TabbedPage

    - NavigationPages

Now I want to go from a page inside the `TabbedPage` to another page with `Navigation.PushAsync()`, but when I do that, I get the new page on screen with the `TabbedPageBar`. That is not what I want, I want to use the root `NavigationPage` to go to another page, so when click back I come back at the `NavigationPage` inside the `TabbedPage`.

Here is some code:
**App.xaml.cs:**

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage (new MainPage());
```

**MainPage.xaml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MyApp.Views"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            x:Class="MyApp.Views.MainPage"
            xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
            android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom"
            BarBackgroundColor="White"
            BarTextColor="Black"
            android:TabbedPage.BarItemColor="#B2B2B2"
            android:TabbedPage.BarSelectedItemColor="#56D7A5"
            android:TabbedPage.IsSwipePagingEnabled="False">    

    <TabbedPage.Children>
        <NavigationPage Title="Page1" IconImageSource="navbar_page1">
            <x:Arguments>
                <views:page1 NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False" />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    </TabbedPage.Children> 
</TabbedPage>
```

**page1.xaml.cs:**

```
private void OpenPage()
{
    Navigation.PushAsync(new page2());
}
```

So, to be clear, the result I have now, is that page2 has the `TabbedPageBar`, so I need to use the `NavigationPage` of the root, so the `TabbedPageBar` goes away, but I have no idea how to do that.

Can someone help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a good design to put the Tabbed Page in a NavigationPage .It will has two navigation bar in the app .

Just set the Tabbed Page as MainPage directly .

```
MainPage = new MainPage();
```

Comment: I had that in the beginning, but then I saw this awnser: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56292931/10673107. If I remove the first NavigationPage, I still have the same problem. I want page2 to have no TabbedPageBar. How can I do that?

Comment: Did you try the answer from the link ?

Comment: If I hide the NavBar, then the NavigationBar is hidden, but I only want TabbedPage Bar to be hidden

Comment: With my code above, I have 2 bars on my screen. A NavigationBar and a TabbedPage bar, but I only want to see the NavigationBar, so I need to hide the TabbedPageBar, how can I do that?

Comment: Okay, but is this the right approach how I want it, or should I do it a different way?

Comment: You could have a try .

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will try soon to remove the tabbar

Comment: Your link is for ios, what about android?

Comment: In Android it will disappear in default .

Answer (score 0):

As I understand in your page1.xaml.cs you are calling the Navigation created for the page1 and since i understand you want to navigate inside the Navigation created for the MainPage (that's of Type TabbedPage) I belive the solution to your problem is to replace `Navigation.PushAsync(new page2());` with `Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new Page2())`